# Plot colors change when exporting as SVG file in R

Tags: r, svg, ggplot2

I am generating a figure for publishing that includes a heatmap and when I export it as .svg the colors change.

When I visualize it in R the colors look ok (heatmap colors match the legend colors):
[image]

However, after exporting it to svg the colors in the heatmap look dimmer:

[image]

I think it has something to do with the svg device including a "white border" to every row of the heatmap, as the colors in the legend are unaffected. If you zoom in very closely you can appreciate it:

[image]

I am using the following code to export them. I have tried changing the `bg` and `antialias` parameteres of `svg` but there is no change:

```
svg(filename="test.svg",width = 10, height = 5)
Figure3
dev.off()
```

When I export is as pdf, the colors are ok:

[image]

I guess I will export them as .pdf but I would like to know what is causing this more as a curiosity.

Thanks!

**Edit: added dataset and code to generate the plot:**

From the [package documentation](https://jokergoo.github.io/ComplexHeatmap-reference/book/a-single-heatmap.html#colors), default colors for the heatmap are generated as:

```
colorRamp2(seq(min(mat), max(mat), length = 3), c("blue", "#EEEEEE", "red"))
```

For the blocks in the left I used another palette in the initial example, here I use RColorBrewer and it has the same effect.

I dont think it's a problem of the color palette as it is ok in the legend, I guess it's a problem of a "border" around each row (both the blocks and the heatmap colors are defined as rows of a tile).

Dataset:

https://file.io/l6fL28Cy

Code:

```
library(ComplexHeatmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

Import data:
x = readRDS("data.rds")

#Select number of clusters to plot:
clusters = 7

#Generate dendrogram to make block annotation:
dend = as.dendrogram(hclust(as.dist(1- cor(t(x))),"complete"), hang=-1)

#Create annotation block for heatmap
cl_num = cutree(dend, k = clusters)
cl_col = brewer.pal(clusters,"Set2")
names(cl_col) = unique(cl_num)
cl_col = list(cl_num=cl_col)

row_ha = rowAnnotation(cl_num = cl_num,
                       col = cl_col,
                       annotation_legend_param = list(title = "Cluster"),
                       show_annotation_name = F)
###Create heatmap:
Heatmap(x,
        clustering_distance_columns = "euclidean",
        clustering_method_columns = "complete",
        clustering_distance_rows = "pearson",
        clustering_method_rows = "complete",
        row_split = clusters,
        left_annotation = row_ha,
        show_row_names = F,
        heatmap_legend_param = list(title = "Z-score"),
        column_title = "Treatment",
        row_title = "Genes",
        use_raster = F,
        column_dend_height = unit(0.1, "cm"),
        column_names_gp = gpar(fontsize = 16),
        column_names_rot = 0,
        column_names_centered = TRUE)
```

Comment: I am noticing that the colors in the legend look the same for all, but it's really only the colors that are in the plot region (called the "panel") itself.  Is that correct?  It's probably useful to share some plot code too so we know what you're using.  I take it this is not just `ggplot()`, but the plot is created via an add on, correct?  What's the palette?

Comment: @chemdork123 I updated the initial post with the data and code to generate the figure. I hope it helps!